# Procedure Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I'm having the following errors while trying to create a procedure on MySQL:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into objetivo.historico (id_aluno, id_turma, ano, bim1) values (a_id, a_t' at line 5

As well as in a few other lines on the procedure. The thing is that i can't see where am i making a mistake, since some parts of the code that got errors repeat on the procedure without errors.

This is the plain code:

```
create procedure objetivo.p_atu_historico (in a_id integer, in a_turma
integer, in a_data date, in a_nota double, in a_bim integer)
begin
if(select count(id) from objetivo.historico where id_aluno = a_id and id_turma = a_turma and ano = Format(a_data, '%Y') )= 0 then
    CASE a_bim 
        WHEN 1 THEN (insert into objetivo.historico (id_aluno, id_turma, ano, bim1) values (a_id, a_turma, Format(a_data, '%Y'), a_nota))
        WHEN 2 THEN (insert into objetivo.historico (id_aluno, id_turma, ano, bim2) values (a_id, a_turma, Format(a_data, '%Y'), a_nota))
        WHEN 3 THEN (insert into objetivo.historico (id_aluno, id_turma, ano, bim3) values (a_id, a_turma, Format(a_data, '%Y'), a_nota))
        WHEN 4 THEN (insert into objetivo.historico (id_aluno, id_turma, ano, bim4) values (a_id, a_turma, Format(a_data, '%Y'), a_nota))
        END CASE;

ELSEIF (select count(id) from objetivo.historico where id_aluno = a_id and id_turma = a_turma and ano = Format(a_data, '%Y')) <> 0 THEN
    CASE a_bim
        WHEN 1 THEN (UPDATE objetivo.historico SET bim1 = a_nota WHERE id_aluno = a_id and id_turma = a_turma and ano = Format(a_data, '%Y'))
        WHEN 2 THEN (UPDATE objetivo.historico SET bim2 = a_nota WHERE id_aluno = a_id and id_turma = a_turma and ano = Format(a_data, '%Y'))
        WHEN 3 THEN (UPDATE objetivo.historico SET bim3 = a_nota WHERE id_aluno = a_id and id_turma = a_turma and ano = Format(a_data, '%Y'))
        WHEN 4 THEN (UPDATE objetivo.historico SET bim4 = a_nota WHERE id_aluno = a_id and id_turma = a_turma and ano = Format(a_data, '%Y'))
    END CASE;
END IF;    
end;
```

And here's a printscreen of the lines returning errors:

[image: The errors]

**EDIT**

This is what happends when i put the semi-colon in the end of each WHEN statement:

[image: Errors2]

Answer (score 1):

You have a small syntax error in your procedure.  You need to remove the extra parentheses and insert a semicolon after each statement.  Like so:

```
create procedure objetivo.p_atu_historico (in a_id integer, in a_turma
integer, in a_data date, in a_nota double, in a_bim integer)
begin
if(select count(id) from objetivo.historico where id_aluno = a_id and id_turma = a_turma and ano = Format(a_data, '%Y') )= 0 then
    CASE a_bim 
        WHEN 1 THEN insert into objetivo.historico (id_aluno, id_turma, ano, bim1) values (a_id, a_turma, Format(a_data, '%Y'), a_nota);
        WHEN 2 THEN insert into objetivo.historico (id_aluno, id_turma, ano, bim2) values (a_id, a_turma, Format(a_data, '%Y'), a_nota);
        WHEN 3 THEN insert into objetivo.historico (id_aluno, id_turma, ano, bim3) values (a_id, a_turma, Format(a_data, '%Y'), a_nota);
        WHEN 4 THEN insert into objetivo.historico (id_aluno, id_turma, ano, bim4) values (a_id, a_turma, Format(a_data, '%Y'), a_nota);
    END CASE;

ELSEIF (select count(id) from objetivo.historico where id_aluno = a_id and id_turma = a_turma and ano = Format(a_data, '%Y')) <> 0 THEN
    CASE a_bim
        WHEN 1 THEN UPDATE objetivo.historico SET bim1 = a_nota WHERE id_aluno = a_id and id_turma = a_turma and ano = Format(a_data, '%Y');
        WHEN 2 THEN UPDATE objetivo.historico SET bim2 = a_nota WHERE id_aluno = a_id and id_turma = a_turma and ano = Format(a_data, '%Y');
        WHEN 3 THEN UPDATE objetivo.historico SET bim3 = a_nota WHERE id_aluno = a_id and id_turma = a_turma and ano = Format(a_data, '%Y');
        WHEN 4 THEN UPDATE objetivo.historico SET bim4 = a_nota WHERE id_aluno = a_id and id_turma = a_turma and ano = Format(a_data, '%Y');
    END CASE;
END IF;    
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Statements in a stored program need to be terminated with a semicolon.

```
CASE a_bim 
  WHEN 1 THEN
    insert into ... ;
    --              ^
  WHEN 2 THEN
    ...
END CASE;
--      ^
```

To create  a stored procedure that includes semicolons, you need to *change* the statement delimiter for the session to some string other than semicolon. This will allow the entire `CREATE` statement is seen as a single statement. Just be sure whatever delimiter string you choose, that delimiter string only appears at the end of the statement, and doesn't appear anywhere within the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement.  For example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE myproc 
BEGIN
   SET @a := 1;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**EDIT**

`WHEN` isn't a statement, that's part of the `CASE` statement.

It's the `INSERT` that is a statement, and that's the statement that needs to be terminated. The parens you have around the `INSERT` statement are superfluous, they don't serve any purpose. (I don't think that's a syntax error, but I'm not sure about that, I've never tried doing that before... wrapping a statement in unnecessary parens.

In your example, the semicolon has to follow the `INSERT` statement, which appears *inside* a paren. That is, if you keep those parens around the statement, that closing paren needs to come *after* the statement delimiter.